# return false not working in IE.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

im working on uploadify free version,

when i click on the browse button , im checking for session if session exists browse window will open or else login will open.

```
$sid=1;
$loginsessionid = 2;
<form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onmousedown="return checksession('<?=$sid ?>','<?=$loginsessionid ?>');" >
    <div id="fileerror" class="div_fileError"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="uploadedfiles" id="uploadedfiles" value=""  />
    <input type="hidden" name="queuesize" id="queuesize" value="0" />
    <a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('cancel','*');" onclick="showBrowse();" class="bluebutton">Clear Selection</a>
    <input onclick="javascript:submitForm();" type="button" id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" value="Upload Files" class="bluebutton" />
       <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true" />
        <div id="queue"></div>
</form>
script type="text/javascript">
function checksession(sessid,login_sessid)
{

       if(sessid === login_sessid)
       {
          return true
       }
       else
       {
           //alert("working if i give this alert");
           return false;

       }
    }
</script>
```

But it is working if i give alert in the false condition.

Comment: please guys help me out with some suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Replace `onmousedown` with `onsubmit`, and remove `onclick="javascript:submitForm();"` from your submit button.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion... and what is the use of adding javascript: before submitForm()

Comment: if i put onmousedown only the function checksession is calling otherwise it is not. i have used onclick but it is not working